# What happens when method name and block name are same?

Tags: ruby, codeblocks, yield

I am trying to understand the below behavior:

```
def test
  puts "In Method"
end

test
#=> In Method

test {puts "In Block" }
#=> In Method
```

My interpretation is that `test` is a method and I am passing `{puts "In Block"}` as an argument to this method. Since the method does not use the argument, it is printing the default `"In Method"`. Is it right?

How do we differentiate between a block and method call? Could `test {puts "In Block"}` also have been interpreted as a block? Is `yield` the only way to execute a code block?

Comment: The title does not look to be related to the question.

Comment: I guess you edited it already! Thanks.

Comment: I corrected the grammatical mistakes in the title, but left the content as is. You should correct it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Since the method does not use the [block], it is printing the default "In Method". Is it right?

No, you are wrong. It is printing `"In Method"` because you defined the method to do so.

> Is yield the only way to execute a code block?

No, you can accept a block as a proc using `&`, and call `call` on it.

```
def foo &block
  block.call(arguments)
end
```

Comment: Yes. That's what I mean't. Since I am not passing any argument, it is doing the default - as per the method definition

Comment: The word "default" means something that is overridden (canceled) under certain circumstances. The `puts ...` line in your method definition in no way overridden by anything; it is always executed.

Comment: Okay. My another question was "Is yield the only way to execute a code block?"

Comment: @Zack nope, you can "catch" the block in the variable (it will be transformed into proc object) with `def my_method(&block)` syntax and call your block the same way as you call every other proc: `block.call`.

Comment: Okay. That's something new for me ! Thanks @MarekLipka

Answer (score 1):

As [sawa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28337836/what-happens-when-method-name-and-block-name-are-same/28337953#answer-28338045) had described you why `"In Method"` printed as its  defined in method. If you want to pass argument to method then you have  to initialized parameter to accept argument.

Something like this..

```
def test message
  puts "I am in method"
  puts message
end

test("In Block")
```

**Note:** Method not accept block as argument. Kindly go through this reference link which make you understand all syntax with example:
[Ruby Programming/Syntax/Method Calls](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Method_Calls)

Comment: Though space between method name and parenthesis with its arguments is eventually correct here, it should be removed, because it could be misleading to new Rubyists.

Comment: white space has been removed ... It was typo mistake

Comment: I fear I'm missing something. `puts` anything returns `nil`, which is passed as an argument to `test`. What is the point of that?

Comment: The OP passed a `{block}`; you passed an `(argument)`. When the argument is an expression (e.g. `(puts "In Block")`), the expression is of course evaluated before it is passed, so `nil` is passed after `"In Block"` is printed. Is that your intent?

Comment: Answer is updated and I don't think it returns `nil`

Comment: It's OK now. When you have `puts`, make the first line, `puts "message.nil? = #{message.nil?}" `.

Comment: Yeah I could saw it now.. thanks but I never use like that :)